# Date formatting in php, unexpected result

Tags: php, date, formatting, strtotime

The Script Below:

```
<?php
$postedDate = "Sat May 11 2013 20:36:24 GMT-0700 (PDT)";
$date  = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($postedDate));

echo json_encode($date);
?>
```

Returns the value:

```
"2013-05-12 03:36:24"
```

I expect and want it to return the value:

```
"2013-05-11 20:36:24"
```

Any ideas as to what's going on?

Comment: Its all because of `GMT - 0700`. Remove it from your date, you will get your desired result.

Comment: Thanks Yogesh. I removed "GMT-0700 (PDT)" and got the expected result. If you want to put that as an answer I'll certainly accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `GMT - 0700 (PDT)` and try you will get your desired result

```
$postedDate = "Sat May 11 2013 20:36:24";
$date  = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($postedDate));

echo json_encode($date);
```

[Codepad](http://codepad.org/GaI8Jc0z)

Comment: I actually needed to remove the (PDT) to get the desired result. If you make that edit I'll check it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$str = 'Sat May 11 2013 20:36:24 GMT-0700 (PDT)';
$date  = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('-7 hours',strtotime($str)));

echo json_encode($date);
```

Or set timezone properly using `date_default_timezone_set`.
http://php.net/manual/ja/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: timezone is a much better solution... the truncation of a fixed value on the date is going to lead to more confusion if he switches to a host in a different timezone.